# HTML dropdown menu with links on the left

Tags: html, dropdown

I have the following code, and it works fine, except for the "Contact" link that needs to be the last link.  However, the dropdown always seems to be placed last?

IT is basically the navbar at http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar that I want to create, with 2 additional links after the dropdown link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    float:right;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #111;
}

.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

It does not render correctly, i'm not sure how to change the css to accomplish this.  Or perhaps there is another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the tag of dropdown from `div` to `li`. Probably the browser renders all `li` first and then the `div`.

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>  
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<div>` into an `<li>` try with this.
For you reference, here are 2 sites with examples.
[Example 1](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/website-design/using-css/simple-css-drop-down-menu#html-code)
[Example 2](http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-a-dropdown-menu-with-html-css)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        float: right;
      }

      li {
        float: left;
      }

      li a,
      .dropbtn {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      li a:hover,
      .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #111;
      }

      .dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      }

      .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
      }

      .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #f1f1f1
      }

      .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>



  </body>

</html>
```